# I want to use url's data in method in django

Tags: python, django

I want to use url's data in method. Now urls.py is

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('data/<int:id>', views.data, name='data'),
]
```

I wrote in views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def data(request,<int:id>):
    results = Users.objects.filter(user=id)
    print(results)
    return HttpResponse('<h1>OK</h1>')
```

But I got an error, `formal parameter name expected in <int:id> of (request,<int:id>)`. If I access http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/3, my ideal system print user's data has id=3. I cannot understand how I can do it. What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 4):

You can't do `<int:id>` in the parameters for `data`, that's invalid syntax. It should be just a normal parameter:

```
def data(request, id):
```

Comment: Agreed with Daniel, the official docs provide full demos: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#specifying-defaults-for-view-arguments

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide only `id` in the parameter for `data` as @Daniel Roseman said

Like this:

```
def data(request, id):
```

and in the urls:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('data/<id>', views.data, name='data'),
]
```